# Change the navigation button item on button press

Tags: iphone, button, navigation, switch-statement

I want to be able to change the right navigation bar button to a different button with name and action.

As an Example:

btnOpenImage is pressed and rightNavButton1 changes to rightNavButton2

Comment: Am I getting it wrong? This is just like setting the rightNavigationItem???? What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    -(IBAction) btnOpenImage_Clicked:(id)sender{

//1. IF buttons are UIBarButtonItem then use bellow code
                  // This bellow line for Change the action(Target)
                 [rightNavButton1 setAction:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked)]; 

                 //This bellow line For Change  the Title
                 [rightNavButton1 setTitle:@"rightNavButton2_Clicked"]; 

//OR 2. IF buttons are UIButton then use bellow code

                // This bellow line for Change the action(Target)
                [rightNavButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                //This bellow line For Change  the Title
                [rightNavButton1 setTitle: @"rightNavButton2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIBarButtonItem' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'  I'm getting this error using this code. Any idea why?

Comment: oh its barbutton then use it         [rightNavButton1 setAction:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked)];

Comment: use this code [rightNavButton1 setAction:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked)];     [btnAddBill setTitle:@"rightNavButton2_Clicked"]; instead of my code from my answer ok dude

Comment: Its not working for me. I add the code and it makes no changes at all

Comment: first tell me you set     UIBarButtonItem *rightNavButton1; in .h file ??

Comment: Yeah I have @property (nonatomic, strong)  UIBarButtonItem* actionsButton;

Comment: then in viewDidLoad you assign value and title so just post that code also so i understand please

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *actionsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Actions"                                            
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                   target:self 
                                   action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionsButton; Thats In view did load. (Its named actionsButton, rightNav was an example)

Comment: hey dude here you must assign like actionsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actions" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionsButton;

Comment: Oh ok thanks (this is my first project on iOS and I'm sort of learning as I go)

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly now. And thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[btnOpenImage addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void)aMethod
{
   [rightNavButton1 setTitle: @"rightNavButton2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

}
```