# UIBarButtonItem in UIStoryboard shows error in action method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Added UIBarButtonItem in UIstoryboard and declared action method for UIBarbuttonitem.

when writing code for action method it shows error on this line

```
[_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:NO];
```

and on this line

```
[_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:YES];
```

in the below UIBarButtonItem Action method

that **no visible @interface for uibarbuttonitem declares the selector 'setBookmarkState'**

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender {

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];

    if ([contentViewController.bookmarks containsIndex:currentIndex]) // Remove bookmark
    {
        [_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:NO]; [contentViewController.bookmarks removeIndex:currentIndex];
    }
    else // Add the bookmarked page index to the bookmarks set
    {
        [_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:YES]; [contentViewController.bookmarks addIndex:currentIndex];
    }
}
```

When using storyboard how i can issue target:self action:@selector statement for this

Comment: check has your class UIBarbuttonitem in interface the method setBookmarkState: (or property bookmarkState).

Comment: I can't find any property called bookMarkState in the documentation of UIBarButtonItem...

Answer (score 1):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813797/change-the-navigation-button-item-on-button-press)

```
 -(IBAction) btnOpenImage_Clicked:(id)sender{

//1. IF buttons are UIBarButtonItem then use bellow code
              // This bellow line for Change the action(Target)
             [rightNavButton1 setAction:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked)]; 

             //This bellow line For Change  the Title
             [rightNavButton1 setTitle:@"rightNavButton2_Clicked"]; 

//OR 2. IF buttons are UIButton then use bellow code

            // This bellow line for Change the action(Target)
            [rightNavButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(rightNavButton2_Clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            //This bellow line For Change  the Title
            [rightNavButton1 setTitle: @"rightNavButton2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It might help you. Give a try.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't helped. Instead fixed it like this by writing this way _bookmarkbtn.enabled = NO; and _bookmarkbtn.enabled = YES;